# Ubuntu 20.04.3 resolution 3440x1440 iiyama GB3466WQSU

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdmi

I bought new monitor to my home (iiyama GB3466WQSU) for my laptop HP Probook 455R G6.
Currently I tried connecting it via hdmi and I cant use 3440x1440, its not appears on display settings.
I read that this monitor model hdmi supports up to 3440x1440 100hz.

[image: display resolutions settings]

In office Im using another ultrawide monitor Samsung (don't remember model) and it works with 3440x1440 on hdmi.

Trying different sets of cable (good quality HDMI 2.0) and settings resolution manually using `xrandr` and its not working :/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Make sure you use at least an **HDMI 2.0x Premium High Speed (14,4 GBit/s)** cable or **HDMI 2.1 Ultra High Speed (42⅔ GBit/s)** cable (do not use cheap trash cables).

Comment: Yes, I tried already  HDMI 2.0 attached with monitor and good HDMI 2.0 cable from work office.

Comment: Which video driver are you using? Is it Nvidia driver or default one?

Comment: @Myszsoda Im using default AMD Radeon vega 10 graphics

Comment: @L.Z. did you ever figure this one out? I've got the same monitor, running Ubuntu 22.04 with AMD graphics. On another computer running the same Ubuntu version but with an Nvidia GPU, it works. Tried messing with xrandr to no avail.

Comment: @fhd No I didn't. I created same environment on my personal PC so I'm working in home on my PC and on laptop on office. On my PC I don't have problem with resoultion on this monitor.